# Stop Callback function Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The user can choose a month (+1 month click, -1 month click)

Each click executes a loop of the number of days in the month choosen.
Inside the loop a function to get data from an $http request.

Problem is: (example)
-Page loads : `var data = [];`

-Time 1: User clicks on January:
 31 $http request are made, 15 callbacks came out.
 `data.length = 15;`

Time 2 : User clicks on February.
variable is initialized `var data = []`
16 callbacks are coming from previous month + 30 callbacks from February.

I'd like a way to stop the callbacks when the user clicks on another month...

Here is a basic Fiddle for better understanding
http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/318/

Comment: The code related to your question goes ***in*** your question, not just linked.

Comment: Are you actually performing one AJAX request per day in the month? In the name of the Great Designer, *why?*

Comment: I didn't saved the fiddle, so made it again

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It isn't an AJAX request but communication with a REST API. We made one request per day because of another part of the application. We used this again, because we saw time to perform 30 request is the same as 1 big.

Comment: Invoking REST APIs implies HTTP requests, usually through AJAX (asynchronous requests). You're performing *days in month* requests to your server instead of a single one per month, which may be comparable in your tests but won't be in the field, trust me. You should review your design.

Comment: Problem is I'm not developpping alone, back end is not changeable, need to find a solution with this logic...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi do you think my answer is acceptable?

Comment: @gr3g, it does prevent subsequent requests from being sent until the previous ones have returned... but it does not alleviate the multiple requests issue, and arguably introduces unacceptable delays in UI reaction (since clicking another month will now do nothing until all the pending requests have returned or failed).

Comment: I agree, but under those circumpstances I didn't found better solution. This was only a problem when user's trying to click very fast or if he has a bad 3g connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok sorry, the fiddle was wrong ...

I guess your requests are not as fast as one request. But since angular is async and you do not "wait" in your next() and previous() functions they overlap each other when you click fast enough.
Then it will return the "rest" from the previous days left and execute the next days of the month.
You need to use promises here or change your program structure.

Edit:

You need to inject $q

Example with promises

```
$scope.next = function(){
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    $scope.data = [];
    // disable previous and next button
    $scope.loadData().then(function(allDayRequestResults) {
        $scope.data = allDayRequestResults;
        // enable previous and next button
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // handle http request error here
    });
};

$scope.loadData = function(){
    var promises = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth(); i++){
        promises.push(getData(i));
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
};

function getData(i){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http(<yourHttpOptions>)
        .success(function(result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('$http-error:' + data + status + headers + config);
            deferred.reject('Error occured while retrieving day '+ i);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Untestet so far ...

Comment: You get it right. Could you give me an example of a promise?

Comment: Edited answer with a promise example.

Comment: @StefanO, I have two questions. Why are you expecting promises to fare better than plain callbacks in this question's context? And where exactly are you aborting the requests for the days that are not in the selected month anymore?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: You are right, you could also use plain callbacks but they normaly mess up the program structure more than promises.
This is only a workaround. I would not abort the already sent requests (I don't even know if this is possible ...) I would disable the possibility to send new requests before the last were finished.

Comment: I thought the questioner is using angularjs in his scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I agree requesting 1 callback with a response of 30 days is a better solution, but I believe this can be usefull for other applications.

This is not tested, but shows the way to proceed.
Global variables are the solution I found, since promises aren't crossbrowser.

```
<button ng-click="load()"> Load data 1.000 times </button>

<script>

var callback = true;
var count = 0;

function ajaxRequest(i){

   //AJAX REQUEST
   .success(function(){

       count++;
       if(count == 1000){
         callback = true;
         count = 0;
       }
    });


}

$scope.load = function(){

   if(callback){
     callback = false;

     for(var i = 0; i < 1001; i++){
        ajaxRequest(i);
     }

   }

}
</script>
```